# Creating a database - Pizza scenario

Tags: sql, erd

I have been assigned to create a database based on any scenario I choose. My scenario is to base it off of Pizza hut.

My problem is making individual orders being listed and determining if service is in the right place in my ER diagram.

This is the scenario:
"Pizza hut is a pizza company that employs workers to sell it’s primary products, pizza to customers. Pizza hut also sells other products such as drinks and chicken. Pizzahut wants to build a database to record data on what foods did customers order. We also want to record the employees who serviced a customer."

I have created relations like so:
Customers (custNo, custFname, custLname, age, suburb, address, gender)
Employee (EmployeeID, EMPfname, EMPlname, position, gender)
Order (OrderNO, productID Quantity, Date )
Food (productID, name, price, stock)
Service (CusNO*, EmployeeID*, ServiceDate)

[ER diagram - draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2sv7.png)

Comment: What's the point on the relationship between `EMPLOYEES` and `CUSTOMERS`? Some kind of relationship like agent/client?

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question, in your question.

Comment: The relationship between `Order` and `MenuItem` (or `Food` in your text description) should probably be many-to-many.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point on the relationship between `EMPLOYEES` and `CUSTOMERS`? Some kind of relationship like agent/client?

For me, an `order` belongs to a `customer`, and one `customer` can have many orders. So it's a one to many relationship.

I would associate the `employee` (if it's a kind of agent/customer relationship) to the `orders` table, bearing able  to query the `customer`s by the `order`s they made. The relationship between `employee` and `orders` would be one to many.

I don't understand well what the `service` table stands for, and why it's different from `orders`

Comment: The `employee`-`order` relationship _might_ be many-to-many, if multiple employees can work on a single order. The scenario in the OP isn't really clear on this matter. But overall, your description seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

I probably should clear things up. NOTE: have updated my ER table since posting the question.

My question: Is my database design reasonable?

-A Customer can be serviced by an employee
-We use Service to identify which employee serviced which customer

[image: Updated ER diagram]